# How do I create Ambient Class Declarations in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a .d.ts file for the KineticJS library. So far I have created the following interface declaration "kinect.d.ts".(I cropped the code a bit for stackoverflow but I hope you get the idea)

```
module Kinetic {

    interface Rect extends  Shape {
        constructor (config) ;
    }

    interface Shape extends Node
    { 

    }

    interface Node {
        constructor (config);
        clone(attrs): Node;
        getAbsoluteOpacity(): number;
        getAbsolutePosition(): any;       

        /*
        other methods removed for stackoverflow example
        */
    }
}
```

I hoped this would be enough to be able to create a Kinetic.Rect object in my app.ts file

```
/// <reference path="Kinetic.d.ts" />
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 239,
          y: 75,
          width: 100,
          height: 50        
        });
```

But it appears I have to do some extra work to use the KineticJS classes (like Rect) in TypeScript. Could anyone give some pointers on how to archive this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at the TypeScript example app at: http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples/imageboard/mongodb.ts

The code at this link creates a definition for the mongodb library. One difference between this and the Sohnee answer is that Sohnee implements the constructor in contrast to the following code snip from the link which is a stub class. I do not have enough reputation to ask Sohnee in the accepted answer why he implemented the constructor for an ambient class?

```
declare module "mongodb" {
   export class Server {
       constructor(host: string, port: number, opts?: any, moreopts?: any);
   }
   export class Db {
       constructor(databaseName: string, serverConfig: Server);
       public open(callback: ()=>void);
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will have a look at it tonight

Comment: Yes this is it! This is what I was looking for. Now I can write `var server = new mongodb.Server("", 1, "something", "");` without having to cast to the right type.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my working example of creating ambient definitions for your Kinetic class:

```
interface Shape {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

interface IKinetic {
    Rect(shape: Shape);
}

declare var Kinetic: IKinetic;

var rect = <Shape> new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 239,
  y: 75,
  width: 100,
  height: 50        
});
```

Note that I have used `declare var Kinetic: IKinetic;` to tell TypeScript that Kinetic is of the particular type.

**Update - Example 2**

```
interface IShape {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

interface IRect extends IShape {

}

module Kinetic {
    export class Rect implements IRect {
        public x: number;
        public y: number;
        public width: number;
        public height: number;
        constructor(rect: IShape) {
            this.x = rect.x;
            this.y = rect.y;
            this.width = rect.width;
            this.height = rect.height;
        }
    }
}

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 239,
  y: 75,
  width: 100,
  height: 50        
});
```

Comment: Hi Sohnee, your example seems to work, but Ideally I would like to return the Type Rect (or as in your example the type Shape). That way Intellisense shows all methods of the returned type. I tried adding :Shape to your example 
    interface IKinetic {
        Rect(shape: Shape);
    }
but then I get the compiler error "new expression only valid on constructors"

Comment: I have added a second example to demonstrate something I think is a bit closer to what you want in your comment.

Comment: Ah nice suggestion but alas. I can't use the second example since I want to create an interface for an existing library(http://www.kineticjs.com). Therfore I don't want to implement the interface (that script already exists). But your first suggestion put me in the right direction so I will mark it as the answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The solution I found is to use Sohnee 's first example with a small change `var rect = <Shape>new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 239,
  y: 75,
  width: 100,
  height: 50        
});` . This way you keep the Intellisense intact.

Comment: @RalphdeRuijter good idea to use a cast to help things along - I've updated the example to include that.

Answer (score 0):

ITodoStorage is really interface, TodoStorage is implementation, but I would not like to define class, because that would force me to implement all members. Instead I make TodoStorage interface as well. Finally I declare var as constructor with new keyword.

```
declare interface ITodoStorage {
    get_todos() : TodoItem[];
    set_todos(value : TodoItem[]) : void;
}

declare interface TodoStorage extends ITodoStorage {
}

declare var TodoStorage : { 
    new (): TodoStorage;
}
```

Then I'm able to call the constructor

```
var storageService : ITodoStorage = new TodoStorage();
```

Unfortunately the var is hiding the TodoStorage type.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is now old, but you can find a completed kinetic.d.ts file here : http://kineticjstypescript.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hehe yes that is the definition I made after resolving my issue :)